# Django migration for different apps

Tags: python, django

I am having different apps in my django project.
Each app containing one models.py file and it contains n no of tables.
I am having only one database.
When am migrating all the models.py files has to migrate at a time and all the tables sit in to same database(only one database).
How to achieve this in django?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: But in case of multiple databases what is the way to do?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate --database=databasename`

Comment: What I mean is am having tables from multiple databases in different apps. So when I am migrating the table has to migrated for respective db. Actually this is my case.

Comment: Please look into this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate